# Using croppie to crop images without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, croppie

I am trying to add an image cropper to a website I am working on. The example I am basing it on is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/afb76b7f/8/

The JS panel claims it is plain javascript, but it uses JQuery too ( if I am not wrong, not familiar with it at all ).
I am trying to remove it, to keep the website as easy to maintain as possible, but I am getting an error.

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="demo-basic">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#page
{
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
}

#demo-basic {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    var basic = $('#demo-basic').croppie ( {
        viewport: {
            width: 150,
            height: 150
        }
    });
    basic.croppie('bind', {
        url: 'https://i.imgur.com/xD9rzSt.jpg',
      });
});
```

So, from what I understand, the first $( function () ) can be simplified by calling the onLoad method, and $('demo-croppie' ) can be simplified by using document.getElementById ( 'demo-croppie' )

So, the page imports the croppie javascript files

croppie.js
croppie.min.js

And tried to simplify the script like this ( onLoad event of page body )

```
var basic = document.getElementById('demo-basic').croppie({
    viewport: {    
        width: 150,
        height: 150
    }
});

basic.croppie('bind', {
    url: previewPictureSource,
});
```

But I get a reference error:

```
ReferenceError: croppie is not defined
```

I cannot find the croppie function anywhere, or understand how to associate it to an object.

Is there an obvious solution to this problem?

I am also happy to try any other library which crops image with a square resulting image, if anybody has more to suggest

Comment: so strange i don't see any problem in youre fiddle :)

Comment: @DuuudeXX8 The fiddle is the working copy which I am trying to use in my website, but I would like to get rid of jquery to make it easier to maintain and understand - should there be problems in the future. The code I am using, jquery free, is that in the body of the question

Comment: `$('#demo-basic')` returns a jQuery Object, whereas `document.getElementById( 'demo-croppie' )` (note I removed the white-space before the opening parenthesis) returns a DOM nod; they are not the same thing. Incidentally the JS panel being set to 'JavaScript + No Library (pure JS)` just means that no JavaScript library is being imported by default; the resources panel on the left specifies that there are three external files being used, one of which is jQuery 3.1.1`.

Comment: @DavidThomas I copied and pasted the code from the jfiddle, and I can work my way back to normal javascript when I have the time... For now I can just leave jquery there. I am still getting an error though: "TypeError: $(...).croppie is not a function". I can hardly argue with that because neither jquery or croppie javascript files have a "function croppie () { ... }" I really can't find that function anywhere. Any idea where I could look? Or are jquery functions different from normal ones?

Comment: @DavidThomas No idea how it fixed things, but I just had to add jquery's file before croppie's one, so I can take it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call .croppie() on `basic` because you initialized it using VanillaJS. However, you can call .bind() on it directly:

```
basic.bind({                                                                 
    url: previewPictureSource
});
```

The documentation specifies that you can interact with a Croppie object in the following two ways:

```
// with jQuery
$('#item').croppie(method, args);
// with VanillaJS
croppieObject.method(args);
```

Check out the documentation here: https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/